# Why FLAIR does't recognize the entire location name

Tags: deep-learning, data-science-model, named-entity-recognition

I'm tying to to detect simple location with NER algorithm, and I'm getting semi-corrected results:

```
from flair.data   import Sentence
from flair.models import SequenceTagger

tagger   = SequenceTagger.load('ner')
text     = 'Jackson leaves at north Carolina'
sentence = Sentence(text)

tagger.predict(sentence)
for entity in sentence.get_spans('ner'):
    print(entity)
```

Output:

```
Span [1]: "Jackson"   [− Labels: PER (0.9996)]
Span [5]: "Carolina"   [− Labels: LOC (0.7363)]
```

I was expecting to receive "north Carolina".

1. Can FLAIR detects full location description ? (what do we need for it ?)
2. Is there any NER algorithm that cat detects full location description ?

Comment: I just saw this question. The answer is essentially the same as the one I gave yesterday: the NER model uses the clues it finds in the sentence, and sometimes there aren't enough clues to find the correct answer. In this case I suspect that an capital N in "North" would have helped.